# How to find results that don't contain results on the same day

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to figure out how to get a set of results returned to me in SQL.

I have a column called "Status" that has either 'Passed' or 'Failed' as a value. Within the same table is a column for "Date_Entered"

I need a query to return all of the days that 'Failed' that do not have a 'Passed' for the same day.

Example:

```
01/01/2017 - Failed
01/01/2017 - Failed
01/01/2017 - Failed
01/01/2017 - Passed

01/02/2017 - Failed
01/02/2017 - Failed

01/03/2017 - Passed
```

In my result set, I only want to see both entries on 01/02/2017 since the 1st and the 3rd has a 'Passed' result.

Here is my most recent attempt:

```
select COUNT(*)
        , CAST(h.Status AS VARCHAR) status
        , CAST(h.Location AS VARCHAR) location
        , CAST(h.Date_Entered AS DATE)

from de_Hgb h
where 1=1
and h.Date_Entered between '01/01/2017' and '01/31/2017 23:59:59'
and h.status not in (SELECT CAST(g.Status AS VARCHAR) status FROM de_Hgb g WHERE 1=1 and g.Status <> 'Passed' AND g.Date_Entered = h.Date_Entered)
GROUP BY h.date_entered, h.Status, h.location
```

However, this is returning the inverse of what I want; this is showing me the entries for the 1st and the 3rd, not the 2nd.

Comment: Can you see the flaw in this statement: SELECT 3 BETWEEN 5 AND 4;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way - select all the failed dates, then left join against the same table on those dates with a 'Passed' status. Then you just need rows where that is NULL (i.e. there was no Passed status)...

```
SELECT DISTINCT failed.Date_Entered 
FROM de_Hgb AS failed 
LEFT JOIN  de_Hgb AS passed 
  ON(passed.Date_Entered=failed.Date_Entered and passed.Status="Passed")
WHERE failed.Status="Failed" AND passed.Status IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked brilliantly. I feel stupid for not thinking of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(date_entered as date) as date_entered
from de_Hgb h
where date_entered between ...
group by cast(date_entered as date)
having
        count(case when Status = 'Failed' then 1 end) > 0
    and count(case when Status = 'Passed' then 1 end) = 0
```

A variations on that that are equivalent assuming those are the only two possible values:

```
having count(case when Status = 'Failed' then 1 end) = count(*)
having max(Status) = 'Failed'
```

It's probably safer to use the first choice in case you introduce new states later.